# regex - difference between $\Lambda+(a+b)^*b$ and $(b+aa^*b)^*$

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

[image: FA]
$r_1=\Lambda+(a+b)^*b$
$r_2=(b+aa^*b)^*$
$r_3=b+\$+aa^*b+(b+\$+aa^*b)(b+aa^*b)^*(b+\$+aa^*b)$

For this FA, which i think of as accepting "$\Lambda$ or anything ending in $b$", i came up with $r_1$, then i used [FSM2Regex](http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm2regex/) which gave me $r_3$ which i simplified into $r_2$ using [regex simplifier](http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/regex_simplifier/).
now $r_2$ seems better than $r_1$. **Should I go with it?** If so, what is lacking in $r_1$? I can't see the difference between $(a+b)^*b$ from $r_1$ and $(aa^*b)^*$ from $r_2$. Is one the subset of other? Are they overlapping or disjoint?

Inputting any of the three RE's back into [FSM2Regex](http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm2regex/) gives RIDICULOUSLY complex TG's especialy because for some reason that is beyond me, it also draws $\$$ (null string) transitions. Even $r_3$ doesn't give back the FA I used to generate it. So my question is : are $r_1$ and $r_2$ different? How? what should I go with?

Comment: 1) Tool requests are offtopic here. 2) The backtick has a different meaning in LaTeX; there is no Markdown nested in MathJax. You can get a plain dollar in LaTeX by `\$`.

Comment: @Raphael , are tool requests completely disallowed on all SE sites or is there some place where you discuss that stuff? also, i don't know if there's some way to PM/chat other user for general discussion, so is there?

Comment: @Awaisome There's [softwarerecs.SE], but I don't know how they do for specialized requests like TCS-specific tasks. For chatting, there's [chat]; you'll need a modest amount of reputation across the whole network to join, though.

Comment: @Raphael, Awaisome: [softwarerecs.se] accepts questions about highly specialized software, but the likelihood of finding someone who can answer is not high. If you consider posting there, do read the [question guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/352).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the regular expressions $r_1=\Lambda+(a+b)^*b$ and $r_2=(b+aa^*b)^*$ are equivalent.  There are several ways of doing this.

1. Just observe that both of them match the empty string and all strings ending with $b$.
2. Convert them to automata and then produce automata for $L(r_1)\setminus L(r_2)$ and $L(r_2)\setminus L(r_1)$. Minimize both automata and find that they both accept the empty language.  (Actually, you'll find that you make a ton of mistakes and at least one of the automata accepts something, and at least one of the minimizations is wrong. But, if you were a computer, this wouldn't be an issue.)
3. Clearly both regular expressions match the empty string, so let's show that they match the same non-empty strings, too.  Suppose that $w\in L(r_2)\setminus\{\Lambda\}$. Then we can write $w=w_1\dots w_\ell$ where each $w_i$ is a string that either matches $b$ or $aa^*b$. In particular, $w_\ell$ must match one of these things, so the last character of $w_\ell$ is a $b$, so $w\in L(r_1)$.

   Conversely, suppose that $w\in L(r_1)\setminus\{\Lambda\}$. Write $w=s_1\dots s_n$, where each $s_i\in\{a,b\}$. Suppose there are $\ell$ $b$s in $w$ and let these be at positions $p_1, \dots, p_\ell$. Because $w\in L(r_1)$, $p_\ell=n$ (the last character is $b$).  For convenience, let $p_0=1$. We can now write $w=w_1\dots w_\ell$, where $w_i=s_{p_{i-1}+1}\dots s_{p_i}$. For each $i\in\{1, \dots, \ell\}$, we have $w_i=a^{p_i-p_{p-1}-1}b$, so each $w_i$ matches either the regular expression $b$ or $aa^*b$. Therefore, $w$ matches $(b+aa^*b)^*= r_1$.

By the way, a fourth equivalent regular expression is $(a^*b)^*$, which you can see by observing that the inner part of $r_1$ is equivalent to $b+a^+b$, which is $a^*b$.